Not able to resolve any hostnames inside docker container using WSL2, docker-ce and DDEV
I am currently not able to resolve any hostnames inside my DDEV web container.
curl www.youtube.com is working perfectly fine inside WSL 2, but once I ssh into the ddev web container using ddev ssh and run curl www.youtube.com, I get the following error:

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.youtube.com


I just fixed it through creating a daemon.json inside my WSL 2 Ubuntu installation (\\wsl$\Ubuntu\etc\docker\daemon.json), with the following content:
{
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
}

Afterwards, I just had to run ddev poweroff, restart wsl running wsl --shutdown in a powershell instance and restarting my ddev project again.

8.8.8.8 is Google's public DNS server. 1.1.1.1 would work the same (Cloudflare's publilc server). The idea is to convince Docker to use a reliable DNS server.

Please edit to show that you made this change in the WSL2 distro, right? It would make this answer stronger if you give a link/hint to how or why you did it.

I edited the file path to make it clearer, where to create the file and mentioned, that I am using Ubuntu as my WSL 2 distro..
